# clojure defrecord named parameters?

Tags: clojure

Does defrecord support named parameters? i.e. if if I have something like this:

```
(defrecord Person [name age])
```

Can I do something like this:

```
(Person. {:age 99 :name "bob"})
(Person. :age 99 :name "bob")
```

The only thing I see by googling is stuff like this:

```
(Person. "bob" 99)
```

Which seems less clear...

Comment: Added in Clojure 1.3, defrecord automatically creates a constructor which takes a map called e.g. map->Person

See http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/defrecord+improvements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently.

But you can just forget about naming the parameters and use an extension map:

```
(defrecord Person [])

(Person. nil {:age 99 :name "bob"})
```

I personally find this to be the easiest way to use records when you have large numbers of possible fields.

Comment: thanks, I'll mark this as the correct answer since it seems like the most reasonable workaround.

Answer (score 4):

Not built in, but you could use something like:

```
(defmulti make-instance (fn [class & rest] class))
(defmacro defrecord* [record-name fields]
  `(do
    (defrecord ~record-name ~fields)
    (defmethod make-instance (quote ~record-name) [_# & {:keys ~fields}]
      (new ~record-name ~@fields))))
(defrecord* Person [name age])
(make-instance 'Person :age 99 :name "bob")
```

Not sure how suitable that would be for what you want.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is not yet supported by clojure?

http://david-mcneil.com/post/765563763/enhanced-clojure-records